# if statement doesn't stop execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

It's been one or two weeks since I started learning to code and I am trying to create a "Press Key To Play" type thing. I've tried everything i know and still get the same results every single time.

In sum, i have an if statement which checks if the game has already started `if gameStart === false`, then, if `gameStart` happens to be false, run a code to detect keypresses on the keyboard + run the game code.

```js
let gameStart = false;

const runGame = () => { console.log(`game running`, { gameStart }) }

if (gameStart === false) {
  $(document).keydown(function () {
    runGame();
    gameStart = true;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
click on me and then press any key
```

I've tried multiple variations, including `else if`, While Loops and changing the order of precedence.
The browser's dev tools even say that `gameStart` is indeed true, but the code runs regardless.

Either the code is stuck and keeps detecting keypresses or it doesn't do it at all.

Please, I know I might be doing something fairly dumb to get the same results all the time, but i need help lmao.

Comment: put the if inside the keydown function, Right now you're checking whether to add the keypress event or not

Comment: Event listeners are subscriptions, they execute every time the event (_keydown_ in your case) occurs and will continue to do so until explicitly removed

Comment: Your "keydown" handler does not check the flag. You add the event handler, and it *does not go away*. Therefore, every subsequent key press will trigger that handler again, and (because it does not internally check the `gameStart` flag before running the game), even if `gameStart` is `true` it'll run the game again.

Comment: Downvoted because of how unlikely it is for someone to have a similar problem (and understand that the problem is similar). I'd advise looking at the [mre] page and trying edit the question to have something reproducible that one can understand quickly.

Comment: @AngryJohn hey I'd be glad to discuss this on meta, but the downvote is not directed to the guy, but rather to question not helpful to the community. Note that I've made I think almost every edits necessary, lets see what OP think of it and if it helps them by any mean for later questions. Maybe a close would have given a warmer intention. My opinion: *downvote and explain* (and as I just saw, they get a +3 -3, so about reputation, I think they are in luck!). OP: for you to get one more upvote (mine) it would need a bit more, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 4):

- Me: Hey Joe, did we start the game yet?
- Joe: No, we haven't.
- Me: Okay then, if so, when you hear a whistle, yell to start the game.
- Joe: Okay, boss.
- Ref: [whistles]
- Joe: START THE GAME!
- Fan: [whistles]
- Joe: START THE GAME!
- Kettle: [whistles]
- Joe: START THE GAME!
- Me: Joe, the game is already running, why are you yelling?
- Joe: You didn't tell me to stop yelling when I hear a whistle.
- Me: I asked you if the game started!
- Joe: Yeah, but that was *then*.

In order to do what you want, there are two ways to do this:

- Tell Joe to check if the game is running every time he hears the whistle, and not mindlessly yell on reflex.

  ```
  let gameStarted = false;

  $(document).keydown(function () {
    if (!gameStarted) {
      runGame();
      gameStarted = true;
    } 
  });
  ```
- Tell Joe to stop listening for a whistle once he starts the game.

  ```
  function gameRunner() {
    runGame();
    $(document).off('keydown', gameRunner);
  }

  $(document).keydown(gameRunner);
  ```
- You can also tell Joe to only listen to the first whistle, but this is the same as telling Joe to stop listening after the first whistle (i.e. jQuery's `one` is doing what the previous example showed, under the hood):

  ```
  $(document).one('keydown', runGame);
  ```

Comment: Great way of explaining how the code is executed! 

Comment: i thought it worked more like
• Me: hey joe, did we start the game yet?
• Joe: No, boss.
• Me: Then when you hear the whistle run the game and ignore other whistles
• Joe: Ok, boss.
• Ref: [whistles]
• Joe: START THE GAME!
• Fan: [whistles]
• Joe: I've already started it

Comment: Yep, it doesn't. Notice that in your code `if` is outside the `keydown` handler, and thus does not execute when `keydown` happens, unlike `runGame`. If you want your code to check something every time an event happens, you need to check it inside the handler, like in my first example.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and effort, it was of great help to me :)